# TryEnterFullScreenMode does not call Page.SizeChanged UWP XAML

Tags: vb.net, events, resize, fullscreen, uwp-xaml

In my code it is dependent on Page.SizeChanged being called but when I use ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryEnterFullScreenMode it does not call Page.SizeChanged if there is any way to call Page.SizeChanged and BTW I need to have both oldSize and newSize in the eventArgs variable

```
    ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryEnterFullScreenMode
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce your  issue. ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryEnterFullScreenMode() does call Page_SizeChanged and you do get SizeChangedEventArgs e.NewSize and e.PreviousSize.

Comment: It does not matter now, I called it manually